# how to find repeated value and count in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table with 3 columns, now how find value if it appears next 3 times immediately
i.e 1st trnas_value appears in next 3 consecutive times (repeaded 4 times) and 2nd and 6th also rows also repeated the same.date column is sorted from A_Z

```
date               tran_val                name
23mar                22                    mark
24mar                22                    mark
25mar                22                    mark
26mar                22                    mark
27mar                22                    mark
28jan                99                    john
29jan                99                    john
30jan                99                    john
31jan                99                    john
```

**output**

```
name     trans_value        consecutive_count
mark       22                   2
john       99                   1
```

we have a code which is not giving the above output..

```
SELECT name, 
        tran_val, 
        MAX(cnt - 3) AS consecutive_count
FROM
(
    SELECT date, 
            tran_val, 
            name, 
            @cnt:=IF(@tran_val=tran_val AND @name=name, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt,
            @tran_val:=tran_val,
            @name:=name
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=0, @tran_val:=0, @name:='') sub0
    ORDER BY `date`
) sub1
GROUP BY name, 
        tran_val
```

any modification in the above code which will get desired output.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `tran_val`, `name`, COUNT(*) - 3
FROM (
  SELECT `date`, `tran_val`, `name`, rn - seq AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT `date`, `tran_val`, `name`,
           @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
           @seq := IF(@name = `name` And @val = `tran_val`, @seq+1, 1) AS seq,
           @name := name,
           @val := tran_val
    FROM mytable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @seq := 0, @name = '', @val = 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY `date`) AS t ) AS s
GROUP BY `tran_val`, `name`, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

You need *two* separate variable to enumerate sequences:

- `@rn` just enumerates consecutive table rows
- `@seq` enumerates consecutive table rows having the same `name`, `tran_val` values.

The difference between these two variables, i.e. `@rn` - `@seq`, identifies *islands* of consecutive table rows having the same `name`, `tran_val` values.

**Edit:** I added a `HAVING` clause to the query so as to filter out islands having a population of 3 or less consecutive rows.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/804c8/4)

Comment: Thanks @giorgos, But if we break the row / continuity of rows i.e after fourth row the value is 26mar   30   mark it is not giving the wright answer it is calculating all the 22's in table - 3 (total 22's - 3) ,so any modifications plz

Comment: @su919 Yes you are right, check the [edit](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/010d9/2) I made.